# Invalid Use of Matcher Exception

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am very new to mockito and trying to write my test cases for this
`getEmployeePorfilebySsoId(String ssoId)`.

**Below is the method**

```
 public List<EcommProfile> getEmployeePorfilebySsoId(String ssoId) {
        List<EcommProfile> profilelist = null;

        try (Sqlsession sqlsession = sqlsessionFactory.openEcomSession()) {
            profilelist = sqlsession.selectList("org.mybatis.ecommprofile", ssoId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**Here is my Testcase for this method**

```
 @Mock
    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;
    @Mock
    Sqlsession sqlsession;
    @InjectMocks
    EcommDaoimpl ecommDao;

    @Test
    public List<EcommProfile> getEmployeePorfilebySsoIdTestException(String ssoId) {
        List<EcommProfile> profilelist = new ArrayList<>();
        EcommProfile ecommProfile = new EcommProfile();
        ecommProfile.setControlNumber("12345");
        profilelist.add(ecommProfile);
        Mockito.when(sqlsession.selectList(Mockito.eq("org.mybatis.ecommprofile"), Mockito.eq("12345")))
                .thenThrow(ApplicationException.class);
        Mockito.when(sqlsessionFactory.openEcommSession()).thenReturn(sqlsession);
        Assertions.assertTrue(ApplicationException.class, () -> ecomDao.getEmployeeProfileByssoId(Mockito.eq("12345")));

    }
```

**Below is the error i am getting** (Unexpected exception type thrown)

````
    Expected: com.mycompany.exception.ApplicationException
    Actual:org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseofMatcherException```.

PS: Please at least give me the hint or something.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question here.

This line `ecomDao.getEmployeeProfileByssoId(Mockito.eq("12345)` is replace to this one `ecomDao.getEmployeeProfileByssoId("12345);`.

Silly mistake was using `Mockito.eq()` inside the `Assertions.assertTrue()` condition as well.